# What mechanism does gdb use to know where to "finish" a function call?

Tags: linux, function, debugging, gdb, execution

In gdb, when debugging inside a function, we can use "finish" command to run to the end of a function.

> My question is: how does gdb know the ending position of a function, especially when there's no debugging symbol to match source code "{}"?

I guess gdb looks for either "leave" or "mov %rbp, %rsp,pop %rbp" under x86 in order to judge whether it has reached the end of a function.

But the problem is,

(1) There're still some extra registers that needs to push/pop at the begin/end of a function call, depending on source code and ABI structure.

(2)The number of registers needs to be push/pop is decided during compilation phase, and I'm afraid this "number" information is not available throw binary executable file.

So, how does gdb determine, where is the end of a function call, so that "finish" command can jump to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gdb doesn't try to analyze the machine code.  Instead, it unwinds the stack, finds the caller's PC, and sets a temporary breakpoint there.  Then it lets the inferior run until the breakpoint is hit.

Due to the way gdb's unwinder is designed, this automatically handles `finish` from an inlined function as well (though there are still a few special cases in the code due to this).